# Define function inside function, and run if exists

Tags: javascript

I am defining a function called Validator. Within this I am defining this.luhn as another function. Now, if the engine parameter is passed to the Validator function, and the engine function exists inside Validator, I would like to run it. At this point, Im getting "Engine for method luhn not found" in my log.

Code:

```
var Validator = (function( cardnumber, cardtype, engine ){
    this.cardnumber = cardnumber;
    this.cards = {"mastercard":"51,52,53,54,55", "visa":"4"};
    this.luhn = (function( cardnumber ){
        var len = cardnumber.length,
            mul = 0,
            prodArr = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]],
            sum = 0;

        while (len--) {
            sum += prodArr[mul][parseInt(cardnumber.charAt(len), 10)];
            mul ^= 1;
        }
        return sum % 10 === 0 && sum > 0;
    });
    if( typeof this.engine != "undefined" ){
        this.engine();
    }
    else {
        console.log( "Engine for method " + engine + " not found" );
    }
});
```

How I initiate it:

```
var test = new Validator( '4861224212948679', 'visa', 'luhn' );
```

Could anyone point me in the correct direction to rung the luhn (or any other function for that matter), if it is defined inside "this" ?

Comment: `this[engine](cardnumber)`

Comment: You should use (typeof engine === "function") instead of typeof this.engine != "undefined". and remove "this." before invoking as it is parameter and not the property of "this".

Comment: Another sidenote: why pass `cardtype` if you can always deduct it off the cardnumber? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bracket notation instead:

```
if (typeof this[engine] === 'function') {
  this[engine](cardnumber);
}
```

... and I'd rather choose `engineName` here instead of `engine` (as you pass names of functions, not functions themselves). Speaking of those, I have to say I would probably prefer dropping this approach in favor of method injecting: define `luhn` function elsewhere, pass it into Validator constructor directly.

```
function luhn(cardnumber) { ... }

// inside Validator function
if (typeof engine === 'function') {
  engine(cardnumber); 
}

var validator = new Validator('5555...', 'Mastercard', luhn);
```

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. I'll accept it in a minute